# Algorithm graph with map reduce

Tags: python, hadoop

I am looking to implement an algorithm from a graph which returns for each user a list of users with whom he is connected with a degree X.

The graph is represented by a file containing in each row of pairs of users connected (the connection is in the 2 direction).

For example :

```
davidbowie  omid
davidbowie  kim
kim torsten
torsten omid
brendan torsten
ziggy   davidbowie
mick    ziggy
```

Here for 1 degree, one must have the following output:

```
torsten brendan kim omid
brendan torsten
ziggy   davidbowie  mick
mick    ziggy
kim davidbowie  torsten
omid    davidbowie  torsten
davidbowie  kim omid    ziggy
```

Each line contains a user and the user list with whom he is connected to 1 degrees.

To run a MapReduce function with python just write the mapper and reducer in separate files after:

```
cat data.csv |  python mapper.py | sort -k1,1 | python reducer.py
```

I am a newbie with hadoop , my problem is what should write in `mapper.py` and `reducer.py` ?

Comment: How big is the dataset? It seems like a natural fit for a graph database (e.g. Neo4j, OrientDB, etc...), rather than write your own mapreduce job. There are Python APIs if that's important to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you'd accept an answer that doesn't explicitly use MapReduce, but thought I'd offer this since it does identify second-degree relationships, it's pretty simple, and would scale.

Assuming you have a Neo4j database running, you can create the graph:

[image: graph of relationships]

... by running this code:

```
from py2neo import Graph

people_pair_text = """\
davidbowie  omid
davidbowie  kim
kim torsten
torsten omid
brendan torsten
ziggy   davidbowie
mick    ziggy"""

people = set(people_pair_text.split())

graph = Graph()

for person in people:
    query = """CREATE (n:Person {{ name : '{0}'}})""".format(person)
    graph.cypher.execute(query)

for pair in people_pair_text.split("\n"):
    person_a, person_b = pair.split()
    query = """
    MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person)
    WHERE a.name = '{0}' AND b.name = '{1}'
    CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)
    CREATE (b)-[:KNOWS]->(a)
    """.format(person_a, person_b)
    graph.cypher.execute(query)
```

Then, to get second degree connections for a given user (e.g. 'omid'), you could run a cypher query like this:

```
MATCH (omid:Person {name:"omid"})-[:KNOWS*2]-some_connection
WHERE some_connection <> omid
RETURN DISTINCT some_connection
```

The query returns:

```
+-------------------------+
| some_connection         |
+-------------------------+
| Node[1]{name:"brendan"} |
| Node[4]{name:"kim"}     |
| Node[2]{name:"ziggy"}   |
+-------------------------+
```

The `*2` in the Cypher query denotes the number of relationships (i.e. 'hops') away, so you could change this if you wanted to return more distant connections.